# IntelliJ: Hide .class files in file search in Maven Java project

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I am working on a Maven Java project using the latest version of IntelliJ CE. I want to be able to view the source code of my Maven dependencies using the IDE's file search tool (ie, ⌘⇧O). However, I am getting both the .java and the .class files for each of the Java class names of a given dependency. Ideally, I only get results for the .java files (source code) instead of the .class files (bytecode). The .class files come from the dependency's JAR file, while the .java file comes from the dependency's sources-JAR file.

Is there any existing way to accomplish this? Thank you.

Comment: Check you haven't added the jar file as a dependency. You only need the sources as a module dependency

Comment: Use `Navigate > Class` instead of `Navigate > File`, you'll only see class names, and it will open source files if they are correctly configured (which is often the case in Maven projects).

Comment: Bastien's answer was the "accepted" answer. I was, admittedly short-slightingly, using `Navigate File` when I should have used `Navigate Class` (⌘O). Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

As answered by Bastien Jansen in the comments, the answer was to use `Navigate Class` (⌘O) instead of `Navigate File` (⌘⇧O).